# What determines object order when creating a Python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need my code to always iterate over the dict items (through `dict.keys()`) in the order they were instantiated. However I noticed that when you instantiate a dict in Python, it will NOT be ordered:

```
>>> dict = {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c'}
>>> dict
{'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b'}
>>> for x in dict.keys():
...     print x
a
c
b
```

How can I guarantee that whenever I iterate through this dict, it will always be in the same order that I created it? And why does Python seem to "scramble" the values whenever I instantiate a new dict?

Note that the order that I talk about here is NOT necessarily alphabetical, numerical or of any other sortable kind.

Comment: As long as you don't alter the keys in the dictionary (insert or delete keys), the order remains stable.

Comment: If you need a fixed order, use an `collections.OrderedDict` object instead.

Comment: See Brandon Rhodes' talk [The Mighty Dictionary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68) for all the gory details on dictionary construction and resizing (if you're interested in the answer to the exact question from your title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `collections.OrderedDict`. [Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)